# isPalindrome homework exercise

Tags: c++

> Write a program that uses the function isPalindrome given in Example 6-6 (Palindrome). Test your program on the following strings:
>
> ```
> madam, abba, 22, 67876, 444244, trymeuemyrt
> ```
>
> Modify the function isPalindrome of Example 6-6 so that when determining whether a string is a palindrome, cases are ignored, that is, uppercase and lowercase letters are considered the same.
>
> The isPalindrome function from Example 6-6 has been included below for your convenience.
>
> ```
> bool isPalindrome(string str) 
> {
> int length = str.length(); 
> for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
>     if (str[i] != str[length – 1 – i]) {
>          return false;
>     } // if    
>   } // for loop
>  return true;
> }// isPalindrome
> Your program should print a message indicating if a string is a palindrome:
> ```
>
> madam is a palindrome

My program so far is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {

bool isPalindrome (string str);
string str;
int length = str.length(); 

cout << "Enter a string: ";
getline (cin,str);

for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
    if (str[i] != str[length -1 -i]) {
         cout << str << "Is not a Palindrome";
         return false;
    } else if (str[i] == str[length -1 -i] && toupper(str[i]) != islower(str[i])) {
        cout << str << "Is a Palindrome";
  } // for loop
return true;
}
```

}

I do not know what im doing wrong I sent everything to make sure it matches the word backwards and then when it is true it will return true. I am very to new to programming and I am sorry if my code is a little sloppy.

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `length`?

Comment: You also don't have an `isPalindrome()` function...

Comment: Your case insensitivity test is a bit confused.  You'll want to do something like `toupper(str[i]) == toupper(str[length - 1 - i])`

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of your code. It wasn't too logical that you were declaring the function inside so i just put it outside.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string str) {
    int length = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[length -1 -i]) {
            cout << str << "Is not a Palindrome";
            return false;
        } else if (str[i] == str[length -1 -i] && toupper(str[i]) != islower(str[i])) {
                cout << str << "Is a Palindrome";
        } // for loop
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main () {

    string str;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline (cin,str);
    isPalindrome(str);
}
```

Comment: Hey Luis I appreciate the comment and just saw it and I copy and paste it into my IDE and also for my homework I need to make it where uppercase and lowercase are the same so if I entered Madam it would say its Palindrome instead of not Palindrome. Im having a hard time doing that for some reason because I made toupper(str[i]) == islower(str[i])) but it wont print anything out if i entered Madam

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = value.Length - 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (i > j)
            {
                return true;
            }
            char a = value[i];
            char b = value[j];
            if (char.ToLower(a) != char.ToLower(b))
            {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX 1000


bool isPalindrome(int x){
  int c[MAX];
  int i = 0;
  int j;
  int k = 0;
  bool z;
  if(x < 0){
      return false;
  }
  while (x != 0){
    int r = x % 10;
    c[i] = r;
    i++;
    x = x / 10;
    }
      for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
      printf("%d ", c[j]);
    }  
  for(k = 0; k <= (i / 2); k++){
    if(c[k] == c[i - k - 1]){
        z = true;
    }
else
    {
      z = false;
    }
  }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).